# How do I create a Body block for a custom Jenkins Pipeline Step in the Java code of my Jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

## Context

I am creating a Jenkins plugin that [adds a custom pipeline step](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-step-api-plugin/blob/master/README.md).

I have successfully got Java code to execute when my step (`dostuff`) is used in a pipeline script, such as

**script1**

```
node {
  stage( 'doingstuff' ) {
    dostuff()
  }
}
```

However, I want my custom step to render some *stages* and *parallel streams* in the Jenkins WebUI visualization, so I want to be doing the equivalent of `parallel([...])` and `stage( ... ) { ... }` and maybe even `node { ... }` blocks in my plugin. For example, if the following were my intended pipeline:

**script2**

```
node {
  stage( 'one' ) {
    parallel([
      "stream one": {
        sh "echo hi from stream one"
      },
      "stream two": {
        sh "echo hi from stream two"
      }
    ])
  }
}
```

I would like to reduce it to

**script3**

```
node {
  dostuff()
}
```

where `dostuff()` will do the equivalent of

**script4**

```
stage( 'one' ) {
  parallel([
    "stream one": {
      sh "echo hi from stream one"
    },
    "stream two": {
      sh "echo hi from stream two"
    }
  ])
}
```

and, importantly, will render properly in the "Pipeline Steps" view of the Jenkins WebUI, and so that the parallel streams will render properly in the Blue Ocean web UI.

While I have seen how to execute the body block that is passed to a custom step defined in a plugin, from a pipeline script ([for example](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-maven-plugin/blob/master/jenkins-plugin/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/maven/WithMavenStepExecution.java#L156)), I cannot figure out the idiom for *creating* a body block in Java code.

I do not want to/cannot do this in pure Groovy because

1. The "real" logic I want to write will depend on classes in several non-Jenkins JARs that aren't on the classpath by default, from several Maven repositories (and so cannot be `import`ed (though they could maybe be `@Grab`'d))
2. The "real" logic I want to write will use concurrency libraries, including Java's `synchronized`, and as far as I can tell pipeline scripts do not support this.
3. The "real" logic I want to write would like to share state across all instances of the logic in the JVM, and as far as I can tell pipeline scripts cannot communicate with other running pipeline scripts.

## Question(s)

1. Is it/should it be possible to create a pipeline body block in Java, and have a custom pipeline step execute that block?
2. Are there any plugins that do this that I could look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke to Andrew Bayer - engineer working on pipeline for CloudBees - at Jenkins World 2017 and he confirmed that it's architecturally impossible to compose a pipeline step of other pipeline steps from pure Java in a Jenkins plug-in.